# How can I ping many hosts (by dns name and resolve it ip addresses) in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have many server DNS names and I want to resolve it ip addreses. How can I do that in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You csn not do this in bash directly. bash does not have builtin support for resolving ip addresses. You do need a proramm that will do it.

You could use `dig`. E.g. if you have your names in a file *hostnamelist* you could use the following script:

```
while read x; do echo  "$x "`dig +short $x A`; done < hostnamelist
```